# Gráfico de área com deslocamento ao clicar e arrastar o mouse

Tags: javascript, lado-do-cliente

Estou com o seguinte desafio: Realizar um gráfico de área em que o cliente possa arrastar as áreas do gráfico(clicar e arrastar) e posteriormente **salvar essa "nova visão"**, após o deslocamento das áreas.

A primeira ideia que me veio em mente foi realizar o deslocamento via Javascript modificando o eixo do gráfico a partir dos eventos de click, mas sentiria uma certa dificuldade para armazenar de volta essas informações na base de dados.

Depois de pensar um pouco sobre, decidi partir do principio de não reinventar a roda, então saí procurando bibliotecas que já fazem isso, porém não é simples assim encontrar.

Então a dúvida é: **Vocês conhecem algum componente/recurso que satisfaça essa necessidade?**
Preferencialmente em ambiente web, mas sendo local também é bem-vindo!

Answer (score 1):

De fato, o ideal não é reinventar a roda, mas você citou: *armazenar de volta essas informações na base de dados*... Ora, qual a dificuldade?

Antes de armazenar no banco, salve as coordenadas X e Y em algum lugar e trabalhe com elas.

Agora falando do "componente/recurso" que você procura, que **eu** conheço, temos o [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) e o [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

Comment: Boa! Gostei desse HighCharts, vou dar uma pesquisada a fundo.

Comment: É show! Dá uma olhada mesmo! E pra te adiantar serviço, [aqui nós temos o que você procura](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) :D